# How to parse ISO8601 into a time_t?

Tags: c, timezone, locale, iso8601

**What is the correct way to parse ISO8601 datetimes into a time_t?**

The input strings are a particular variant of ISO8601 datetimes:

> 1991-02-03T04:05:06.000-07:00
>   *(I do not need to worry about the 'Z' or implied localtime variants)*

I can use `strptime()` to parse up to the fractional seconds, but the man page mentions `setlocale()` so I worry that I need to do something with that.  **Do I?**  Or is that just for things like month and day names?

There doesn't seem to be any way to skip over (or handle) the fractional seconds in strptime, and my version of it doesn't seem to support '%z' anyway (and `tm_gmtoff` is non-standard), so I'm stuck parsing the fractional seconds and time zone offset of the input 'by hand'. Easy enough.

So I assume I can just modify `tm_min` I got from strptime with the number of minutes of TZ offset.  **Correct?**

Then we come to `mktime()`.  It appears that the expected way to force it to function in UTC is:

> get TZ, clear TZ, `tzset()`, `mktime()`, reset TZ, `tzset()`
>   *(there is a `timegm()` but is non-standard)*

I'm going to be processing lots of these strings and I don't care about any other time processing in this program, so this seems like a lot of worthless overhead,  **Can I just clear TZ and `tzset()` once at the beginning?**

Comment: Remember that `time_t` is usually an integer type and counts whole seconds.  Fractions are not really relevant to it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't care about the fractional seconds in this case, but a future reader might be using a `struct timespec` or similar, so I thought I'd say skip **or handle**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can use `strptime()` to parse up to the fractional seconds, but the man page mentions `setlocale()` so I worry that I need to do something with that. Do I?

Yes, unfortunately; depending on the locale, %S might consume fractional seconds, and might look for a decimal comma rather than a decimal point.

Personally, I would do this completely by hand, with `strtok` and `strtol`, filling in the appropriate fields of the `struct tm`.  You do not have to fill in `tm_yday` and `tm_wday` for `mktime` to work.

> I assume I can just modify `tm_min` I got from strptime with the number of minutes of TZ offset. Correct?

This is harder than it looks.  Depending on the actual value of the timezone offset, you will need to adjust `tm_hr` as well as `tm_min` (in fact, the common case is a whole number of hours, so you'll adjust `tm_hr` and not `tm_min`), and if the adjustment pushed the time over a day boundary you will need to normalize the hour and fix up the day, month, and year.

You must also make sure that `tm_isdst` and `tm_gmtoff` are zero and `tm_zone` is NULL.

> Can I just clear TZ and tzset() once at the beginning?

On a system where the "expected way" works, yes.  However, the "expected way" is not guaranteed to work, and in fact if you don't have `timegm` I would expect it *not* to work.

Use `timegm`.  If you don't have `timegm`, [get it from `gnulib`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/timegm.html#timegm).

Comment: I was under the impression that `mktime()` will do the normalization/fix-up for you.

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, what kind of demented platform would have strptime %S consume the fractional seconds?  The standard calls for values in [00,60] and tm_sec is required to be an int.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that writing your own minimalist 'mktime w/o timezone nonsense' isn't that hard.

```
#define divis(y,n) (((y) % (n)) == 0)
#define isLY(y) (divis((y),4) && (!divis((y),100) || divis((y),400)))
#define nLY(y)  (((y) - 1969) / 4 - ((y) - 1901) / 100 + ((y) - 1601) / 400)

static int      mdays[]         = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

/*
 * mktime implicitly applies the local timezone, this doesn't.
 * This also only works with valid values, no checking or normalizing happens.
 */
static time_t epoch (
        struct tm *     tm
) {
        int     years           = tm->tm_year + 1900;
        int     months          = tm->tm_mon;
        int     days            = tm->tm_mday - 1;
        int     hours           = tm->tm_hour;
        int     minutes         = tm->tm_min;
        int     seconds         = tm->tm_sec;

        if ((months > 1) && isLY(years)) ++days;
        while (months-- > 0) days += mdays[months];
        days += (365 * (years - 1970)) + nLY(years);
        return (time_t)((86400 * days) + (3600 * hours) + (60 * minutes) + seconds);
}
```

So, I'll combine this with the suggestion in @zwol 's answer to just parse the string 'by hand' rather than have to deal with `strptime()`, `mktime()` and `struct tm`'s possible idiosyncrasies.